# Scala Spark Convert Dataframe and get all Unique IDs and its type from each row

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have Dataframe like this:

```
+---------+---------+-------------+-------+
|device_id|master_id|time         |user_id|
+---------+---------+-------------+-------+
|X        |M        |1604609299000|A      |
|Z        |M        |1604609318000|A      |
|Y        |N        |1604610161000|B      |
+---------+---------+-------------+-------+
```

What I am trying to do is to get all the unique IDs and the type and first time I see them. I was wondering how can I convert the above-mentioned dataframe to something like this:

```
+---+-------------+---------+
|id |time         |type     |
+---+-------------+---------+
|A  |1604609299000|user_id  |
|X  |1604609299000|device_id|
|M  |1604609299000|master_id|
|Z  |1604609318000|device_id|
|B  |1604610161000|user_id  |
|Y  |1604610161000|device_id|
|N  |1604610161000|master_id|
+---+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: I think you can create 3 separate select, one select query for each type and then union the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add required columns inside `array(struct(<column list>))` & then explode column data.

Check below code.

**Given Data**

```
scala> df.show(false)
+---------+---------+-------------+-------+
|device_id|master_id|time         |user_id|
+---------+---------+-------------+-------+
|X        |M        |1604609299000|A      |
|Z        |M        |1604609318000|A      |
|Y        |N        |1604610161000|B      |
+---------+---------+-------------+-------+
```

Creating expressions

```
scala> val colExpr = array(
        df
        .columns
        .filterNot(_ == "time")
        .map(c => 
                struct(
                    col(c).as("id"), // id column
                    col("time").as("time"), // time column
                    lit(c).as("type") // type column
                )
            ):_*
    )
```

Result of above code is below expressions.

**Note** : Below expression just for understanding how above code is converting into expressions. (Don't execute below expressions.)

```
colExpr: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = array(
    named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), device_id AS `id`, NamePlaceholder(), time AS `time`, type, device_id AS `type`), 
    named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), master_id AS `id`, NamePlaceholder(), time AS `time`, type, master_id AS `type`), 
    named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), user_id AS `id`, NamePlaceholder(), time AS `time`, type, user_id AS `type`)
)
```

**Applying Expression**

```
scala> df.select(explode(colExpr).as("data")).select("data.*").show(false)
+---+-------------+---------+
|id |time         |type     |
+---+-------------+---------+
|X  |1604609299000|device_id|
|M  |1604609299000|master_id|
|A  |1604609299000|user_id  |
|Z  |1604609318000|device_id|
|M  |1604609318000|master_id|
|A  |1604609318000|user_id  |
|Y  |1604610161000|device_id|
|N  |1604610161000|master_id|
|B  |1604610161000|user_id  |
+---+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more on colExpr
it seems my scala compiler doesn't like your syntax

Answer (score 0):

How big is your data set ? this answer might not be efficient , but will work.

Assuming your original dataframe name is someDF

```
someDF.createOrReplaceTempView("someDF")

someDF.printSchema
    root
     |-- device_id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- master_id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- time: integer (nullable = false)
     |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)

someDF.show
    +---------+---------+----------+-------+
    |device_id|master_id|      time|user_id|
    +---------+---------+----------+-------+
    |        X|        M|1604609299|      A|
    |        Z|        M|1604609318|      A|
    |        Y|        N|1604610161|      B|
    +---------+---------+----------+-------+
```

transformation query will look something like:

```
spark.sql("""select device_id as id ,min(time) as time,'device_id' as type from someDF group by device_id
union
select master_id as id, min(time) as time , 'master_id' as type from someDF group by master_id
union
select user_id as id,  min(time) as time , 'user_id' as type from someDF group by user_id
""").sort(col("time"))

res13: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [id: string, time: int ... 1 more field]

res13.show
    +---+----------+---------+
    | id|      time|     type|
    +---+----------+---------+
    |  X|1604609299|device_id|
    |  A|1604609299|  user_id|
    |  M|1604609299|master_id|
    |  Z|1604609318|device_id|
    |  Y|1604610161|device_id|
    |  N|1604610161|master_id|
    |  B|1604610161|  user_id|
    +---+----------+---------+
```

Comment: it's around 400K rows

Comment: Then  the solution provided by srinivas seems to be more efficient. Please make sure to run solution provided by Srinivas on unsorted data. It may provide you the first occurrence in table and not the minimum of timestamp.